# Relative path not working using SystemJS in Angular 2

Tags: angular, systemjs

I have gone through [this article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html)

Here is my code

```
@Component({
  moduleId: __moduleName,
  selector: 'header',
  template: require('./header.component.html'),
  styleUrls: ['/header.component.css']
})
```

The line

`moduleId: __moduleName,`

is giving error: Cannot find name '__moduleName'.

tsconfig.json file:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "sourceMap": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "removeComments": false,
  "noImplicitAny": false
},
"compileOnSave": false,
"filesGlob": [
  "src/**/*.ts",
  "src/**/*.tsx",
  "!typings/**",
  "!node_modules/**"
]
}
```

I am using SystemJS. Please Help!

Comment: Why are you using `template` together with `require` instead of `templateUrl`? It looks like a webpack feature

Comment: `require('...')` belongs to **CommonJS**, 
with **SystemJS** you should do: [`System.import('...');`](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs#browser).

Comment: Actually i am new to this, not sure about the require(...).

I have updated the question. Can you please help me with the error?

Comment: Can you also add your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: @yurzui I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these options:

**CommonJS**

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs", // this line
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

**component**:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'header',
  templateUrl: 'header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['header.component.css']
})
```

**SystemJS**

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system", // this line
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

**component**:

```
declare var __moduleName: any;

@Component({
  moduleId: __moduleName,
  selector: 'header',
  templateUrl: 'header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['header.component.css']
})
```

There are also special loaders to load your html without specifying `module` option (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6053#issuecomment-222341010)

> Webpack users can use require('./some-template.html') - see
>   https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html for an example of
>   how to use this.
>
> SystemJS has the ability to use loaders for text in a similar fashion
>   - https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-text

See also

- [zone.js:344 Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load app.template.html in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503805/zone-js344-unhandled-promise-rejection-failed-to-load-app-template-html-in-ang)
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6053