# Angular2: Failing to load component's templateUrl file

Tags: angular

I am getting the following *Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load* error in my Angular 2 project:

[image]

Here is my messages.component.js:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core"

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'messages',
    templateUrl: './messages.component.html',
})

export class MessagesComponent {
    messages: object[] = [{ text: "this is some text", owner: "Brad" }, { text: "this is a cool article", owner: "Fred" }];
}
```

and messages.component.html:

```
<p>This is the messages Component: {{messages.length}}</p>
<div *ngFor="let message of messages">
    {{message.text}} by {{message.owner}}
</div>
```

I looked at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503805/zone-js344-unhandled-promise-rejection-failed-to-load-app-template-html-in-ang) and this [this article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html) the the path looks correct to me.

Towards the end of [this post](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/issues/893) seems to indicate that the html can fail to build and thus be missing. The html file is indeed missing from the wwwroot after building, but I get no compiler errors.

I am on Windows10 using VS2017. I used [this template](https://adrientorris.github.io/aspnet-core/how-setup-angular-2-typescript-project-visual-studio-2017.html) for setting up the project.

Comment: is messages.component.js and messages.component.html are in the same directory?

Comment: Remove/comment out this line: `moduleId: module.id,`, and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes, they are in the same dir. I also tried every version of the path I could think of before adding the `moduleId: module.id` line.

Comment: Have you tried changing it to an in-line template to see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Inline templates work just fine, both single and multiline.

Comment: Good, I guess. I can tell you this, your code is not the issue. There must be something amiss with the build process you are using.

Comment: Have you checked whether the spelling of filename you are using is same as both side or not?

Comment: As to the build process being amiss, I think I would agree, but I have no idea how to go about debugging it. I have created an issue on the template developer's Github page. I'll update here is I get anything.

Comment: Is there any possibility you have an uppercase/lowercase problem with your template file? Please provide a directory listing showing the files in question.

Answer (score 0):

Your component seems great. I think your error is related to the module declarations. 
Did you add your new component in *app.module.ts* file ?

You should have something like :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
//import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component'; // DECLARE YOUR COMPONENT HERE

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        //FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        //routing,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        MessagesComponent // INJECT YOUR COMPONENT
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: This would not account for the error that the OP is reporting.

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra comma after the `templateUrl`
Since its in the same dir and since you have used `moduleId: module.id`
Try the below code

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'messages',
    templateUrl: 'messages.component.html'
})
```

Comment: The trailing comma is not causing the problem. I have tried every possible combination of path, including that one. I believe the problem lies elsewhere like the build, but that is beyond me right now.

Comment: The extra comma is harmless. It is accepted, valid TS syntax.